# How to search an array for values present in another array and output the indexes of values found into a new array in [mongodb]

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Collection in each document is an array field and I want to search it for the occurrence of elements that are in another array and output the indexes of elements that are found as an array.

For example:

I have a document with foo field,

```
{
        foo = [1,4,3,6,6],
        foo = [1,5,7,5,8],
        foo = [2,4,3,1,6],
        foo = [1,4,9,6,7]
}
```

and an array which contains the elements to be searched

```
bar = [3,6]
```

I want the output to be

```
{output = [2,3]}
{output = [-1,-1]}
{output = [2,4]}
{output = [-1,3]}
```

I have tried using aggregation pipeline and map function with $indexOfArray but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` expression.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
      "output":{
        "$map":{
         "input":[3,6],
         "in":{"$indexOfArray":["$foo","$$this"]}
        }
      }
   }}
])
```

Comment: Just that it is missing a comma after the input array. After putting that, it worked perfectly for me. Thanx for the answer.